# In these threads, what is this Boolean used for?

Tags: java, multithreading, boolean, producer-consumer

Hello I'm having problems understand this code that is presented here, this code shows an example of how to correctly implement wait() and notify() into a thread.

Here's the code:

```
class Q {

  int n;    
  boolean valueSet = false;

  synchronized int get() {
    if(!valueSet)
    try {
        wait();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
    } 
    System.out.println("Got: " + n);
    valueSet = false;
    notify();
    return n;    
  }

  synchronized void put(int n) {
    if(valueSet)
    try {
        wait();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("InterruptedException caught");
    }
    this.n = n;
    valueSet = true;
    System.out.println("Put: " + n);
    notify();
   }
 }

class Producer implements Runnable {
  Q q;
  Producer(Q q) {
    this.q = q;
    new Thread(this, "Producer").start();
  }
  public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
      q.put(i++);
    }
  }    
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
  Q q;
  Consumer(Q q) {
    this.q = q;
    new Thread(this, "Consumer").start();
  }
  public void run() {
    while(true) {
      q.get();
    }
  }
}

class PCFixed {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Q q = new Q();
      new Producer(q);
      new Consumer(q);
      System.out.println("Press Control-C to stop.");
    }
  }
```

I have a hard time understanding the usage of a boolean here, if the boolean variable stays, the the code will print correctly.

However if I take away the boolean, then it will ONLY print "Press Control-C to stop". Why is that?

Why is the boolean so important here and what is its usage?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Q` implements a container for one single integer stored in `n`. This container is used pass that value from the `Producer` to the `Consumer`. Since only one value can be kept at a time by the container, both `Producer` and `Consumer` must know somehow if the Container is full or not. The boolean value `valueSet` is this indicator.

If set to `true`, the container is full, and therefore `Producer` must wait until it's emptied before filling it again. Likewise, if `valueSet` is false, the `Consumer` may not try to retrieve the content of the `Q` instance until there is something to retrieve.

By removing the boolean (and the tests for its state), you put both `Producer` and `Consumer` threads in wait state for a notification (which will likely never happen, since only them were able to generate it in the code), hence the only message appearing is the one from the main thread.

A very important point: as hinted by [Freedom_Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062384/freedom-ben) in his own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15101994/1769720), this code works because both `get` and `put` methods are made `synchronised`, meaning that they will block all other threads trying to access the object through `synchronized` calls during their execution, making these calls atomic with regard to each other. This point is important since it pretty much guarantee that read and write on both `valueSet` and `n` are made atomically. Without that property set on **both** methods, the notification from `put` might occur after `Consumer` has checked `valueSet`  but before it calls `wait`. Depending on the implementation of the notification mechanism (*), this could lead to `Consumer` missing the notification and going into wait state, even though there's a value in `Q`.
With the `synchronized` attribute on these method, we are assured that these calls will behave as intended.

- `synchronized` keyword
- [`notify`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) and [`wait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) methods

---

(*) The `wait` and `notifiy` code can be implemented in two ways:

- the quick way is to have `notify` simply check if a thread is `wait`ing, and wake it up if so, or do nothing otherwise. This is the scenario leading to a race condition without properly `synchronized` method calls.
- the more correct way is to use a dedicated semaphore initialized at `0`, and alias the `notifiy` and `wait` to the `increment` (aka `release`) and `decrement` (aka `acquire`) operations on the semaphore respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the boolean is `valueSet`. When it is true, it means that a value has been set. When it is false, it means that a value has not been set. Think of the boolean as a flag, and when it is true there is data to be consumed (the flag is up), when it is false there is no data to be consumed (the flag is down).

The producer thread will set a value only if the flag is false. If it is true, it will wait to be notified by the consumer.

The consumer thread will only read the value if the flag is true. If it is false, it will wait to be notified by the producer.

Do you have access to and experience with a debugger? Stepping through the two threads and seeing how they interact with each other might help you. If you haven't used a debugger before, multithreading might not be the ideal learning scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the boolean is being used to avoid waiting if the last value hasn't yet been processed.  For example, in the put method we are skipping the wait() if valueSet is true, because that means that get() has not yet run since the last time we updated the value of this.n.  if we wait() each time regardless of the boolean, chances of a deadlock are pretty good, where both threads are waiting and none will notify.

This is a reason why I don't like applying the synchronized keyword to methods.  It can be confusing as to which object is being used as the mutex.  I prefer this style because it is more clear which resource is being waited for.  I also find that this style discourages lazyiness by doing work under a mutex that doesn't need to be synchronized.  It is all personal preference though:

```
void get(int n){
    synchronized(this){
        // do the work
    }
}

void put(int n){
    synchronized(this){
        // do the work
    }
}
```